# Проблема с размер страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивность

моя проблема заключается в слудующем:при добавлении блока, изменяется высота страницы. Как вернуть нормальною высоту страницы? И как удлать часть где нет ничего?[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1] [![Фото][2]][2]

Так же при изменении разрешения окна, текстовые ссылки стоят на  месте а не двигаются. Что с этим сделать? Помогите!!![![фото2[![][2]][3]][3]][4][![фото3][5]][5]

```css
/*Тело*/

body {
  background: url(img/bg.png);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Шапка */

div.header {
  height: 110px;
  background: #101417;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

div.script
/*Название в шапке*/

.name:hover .mid {
  color: red;
}

div.mid {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  color: white;
  left: 0px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/*Меню*/

div.topmenu {
  float: right;
}

div.topmenu a {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -10px;
}

.mid:hover {
  color: red;
}

a {
  font: 16px/24px Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  left: -570px;
  top: -10px;
  color: black;
  /* Цвет обычной ссылки */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Убираем подчеркивание у ссылок */
}

a:visited {
  color: red:;
  /* Цвет посещённой ссылки */
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  /* Цвет ссылки при наведении на нее курсора мыши */
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Часы*/

div.clock {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 110px;
}


/*Menu fon*/

div.menu {
  background: red;
  border: 14px solid red;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}


/*block*/

div.block {
  width: 200px;
}

div.left {
  background: #101417;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 460px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}

div.right {
  background: #101417;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 460px;
  position: relative;
  top: -512px;
  left: 1150px;
}

div.center {
  background: #101417;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 460px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1014px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 811px;
}

#content {
  width: 500px;
  /* Ширина слоя */
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  /* Выравнивание по центру */
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  /* Фиксированное положение */
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Левый нижний угол */
  padding: 10px;
  /* Поля вокруг текста */
  background: #39b54a;
  /* Цвет фона */
  color: #fff;
  /* Цвет текста */
  width: 100%;
  /* Ширина слоя */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>1</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <header>
      <div class="topmenu">
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>



  <div class="clock">
    <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i6e1neb0/n367/tlua41/fn15/fs22/tcff0/pc009/ftb/th1" frameborder="0" width="83" height="28"></iframe>

    <div class="mid">
      <header>
        <h1 align="center">Tunika7</h1>
      </header>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      <div class="topmenu">
        <aside>
          <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
          <a href="#">Создатели</a>
          <a href="#">Login</a>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
      <div class="mid">
        <div class="fon">
          <div class="block">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="center"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Я вижу у тебя незакрытый div.clock (нарушается последовательность - нужно закрыть на 20 строке)

2) У тебя начинается какая-то странная структура (как по мне), Я бы порекомендовал сделать следующее:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="mid">
    <div class="fon">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="center"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Заменить на

```
<div class="content">
<div class="mid">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
   <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

3) У div.center есть параметр top: -1125px на 125 строке - Он и вызывает твою проблему. Позиционировать нужно по другому. - Здесь я ответил на вопрос почему пустое пространство у тебя снизу. Дальше уже идут тонкости верстки. Нужно понимать задачу

Рассказываю исходя из предложенной мной структуры:
Добавляешь div.mid (он у тебя используется в меню), по этому в CSS обратись к нему через .content

```
.content>.mid { display: flex; justify-content:space-between; }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Нужна будет помощь по верстке, можешь обращаться. Помогу разобраться.